# N-queen problem in prolog. How to optimize the queen choice to be more efficient?

Tags: prolog, n-queens

I implemented the N-queen problem with SWI Prolog , but I want to optimize the choice of queen, so it will be more efficient.
Here is my code:

```
safe(_,[],pos(A,B)).
safe(N,[pos(X,Y)|Rest],pos(A,B)):-
   safe(N,Rest,pos(A,B)),
   between(1,N,Y),
   noattack(pos(X,Y),Rest,pos(A,B)).

noattack(Queen,[],pos(A,B)).
noattack(pos(X,Y),[pos(X1,Y1)|Rest],pos(A,B)):-
   X=\=X1, Y=\=Y1, Y1-Y=\=X1-X,Y-Y1=\=X-X1,
   A=\=X, B=\=Y, A=\=X1, B=\=Y1, Y-Y1=\=A, X-X1=\=B,
   noattack(pos(X,Y),Rest,pos(A,B)).

template(N,L):-
   findall(pos(I,_),between(1,N,I),L). 

execute(N,N1,L,pos(A,B)):-
   template(N1,L),safe(N,L,pos(A,B)).

solution(L):-
   write('Please give number N and coordinates for super tower:'), nl,
   read(N),
   read(pos(A,B)),
   N1 is N-2,
   execute(N,N1,L,pos(A,B)).
```

Is there a way to change between(1,N,Y) so the choice of Y will be "more intelligent"?

Comment: N-queens is a *polynomial* problem, so instead of enumerating, one can generate the solution: https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=122322

Comment: If you however look for completion, that is NP-hard, so you can likely find some ways to pick better values, etc. But in general you can not hope to solve that problem for an *N* larger than 200.

Comment: I know that the problem is NP-hard, but I want just to minimize the range of the choice each time, so I will minimize the time to find a solution.

Comment: Well you can each step reduce the domain with the "column" you picked for that row, since no two queens can be placed on the same row.

Comment: Yes, this is a good idea, I will try it. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please help me, because I am new in Prolog, how I will reduce the domain in each step? Do I have to add a new rule to reduce the domain and send it back? Do I have to change all the rule of safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think as "low hanging fruit", we can enforce that no two queens are on the same column (given in each generation we determine the position of the next row), by reducing the "domain" dynamically. This means that we (a) will never yield a situation where two queens are on the same column; and (b) we also can gain performance, since we no longer need to check this.

We thus for example can start with a list of possible columns like `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. If we pick `2` for the first queen, we pass a list `[1, 3, 4]` to the recursive call, and regardless what the recursive call picks, we know that this can not be the same column. For this we need a predicate that picks an item, and at the same time yields a list where we removed that item, like:

```
pick_rem([H|T], H, T).
pick_rem([H|T], P, [H|R]) :-
    pick_rem(T, P, R).
```

This then will generate:

```
?- pick_rem([1,2,3], P, R).
P = 1,
R = [2, 3] ;
P = 2,
R = [1, 3] ;
P = 3,
R = [1, 2] ;
false.
```

An extra bonus is that if the list is empty, we already know that we reached the end of the board, and thus we found a valid solution. So termination can be checked with simple pattern matching instead of numerical comparisons of an index.

We also need a predicate that generates a range, like:

```
range(X, Y, []) :-
    X > Y.
range(X, Y, [X|T]) :-
    X =< Y,
    X1 is X + 1,
    range(X1, Y, T).
```

As for checking that the queens do not attack diagonally, we can construct a predicate that takes two numbers and each time updates the two, like:

```
not_attack([], _, _).
not_attack([H|T], C, D) :-
    \+ H is C + D,
    \+ H is C - D,
    D1 is D+1,
    not_attack(T, C, D1).
```

We thus need to keep track of the positions of the queens, and this in "reverse" order (so the nearest row is the head of that list).

So now we can combine this together in a generate predicate:

```
gen([], _, []).
gen(Dom, Old, [C|Res]) :-
    pick_rem(Dom, C, Dom1),
    not_attack(Old, C, 1),
    gen(Dom1, [C|Old], Res).
```

Here the first parameter is the domain that is "shrinking" each recursive call with one element, the second element is a list that is building up with the columns of the queens we put on the board. Finally the last parameter will "construct" the positions of the board.

So now we only need to wrap this predicate with some logic in a more convenient one:

```
to_pos(R, C, pos(R, C)).

n_queens(N, Sol) :-
    range(1, N, Dom),
    gen(Dom, [], Res),
    maplist(to_pos, Dom, Res, Sol).
```

This then generates the *N*-queens solutions for *N=4* and *N=5* quite efficiently:

```
?- n_queens(4, S).
S = [pos(1, 2), pos(2, 4), pos(3, 1), pos(4, 3)] ;
S = [pos(1, 3), pos(2, 1), pos(3, 4), pos(4, 2)] ;
false.

?- n_queens(5, S).
S = [pos(1, 1), pos(2, 3), pos(3, 5), pos(4, 2), pos(5, 4)] ;
S = [pos(1, 1), pos(2, 4), pos(3, 2), pos(4, 5), pos(5, 3)] ;
S = [pos(1, 2), pos(2, 4), pos(3, 1), pos(4, 3), pos(5, 5)] ;
S = [pos(1, 2), pos(2, 5), pos(3, 3), pos(4, 1), pos(5, 4)] ;
S = [pos(1, 3), pos(2, 1), pos(3, 4), pos(4, 2), pos(5, 5)] ;
S = [pos(1, 3), pos(2, 5), pos(3, 2), pos(4, 4), pos(5, 1)] ;
S = [pos(1, 4), pos(2, 1), pos(3, 3), pos(4, 5), pos(5, 2)] ;
S = [pos(1, 4), pos(2, 2), pos(3, 5), pos(4, 3), pos(5, 1)] ;
S = [pos(1, 5), pos(2, 2), pos(3, 4), pos(4, 1), pos(5, 3)] ;
S = [pos(1, 5), pos(2, 3), pos(3, 1), pos(4, 4), pos(5, 2)] ;
false.
```

On my machine, it works quite effective up to *N=19*. The above is of course not *perfect*. One can think about some heuristics, etc. to pick better positions, or see in advance that certain patterns will fail. Right now we only stop searching a *branch* if there is no way to place the queen on the board. But sometimes a combination of some queens can never yield good results later, and such patterns can be added to avoid exhaustively searching the branch.

Comment: Thank you so much this helps a lot!

Comment: Have you ever chanced upon Bratko's solution to N queens? Hint: he maintains domains not only for columns, but .... (and of course rows need not be numbered, the 8 queens in the solution list are already inherently numbered by their position in the list).

Comment: @WillNess: the diagonals of course. But here we do not store the row number. It is only added as a post-processing for formatting purposes :). As for why the diagonal domain is not maintained, removing might take *O(n)* which is approx. the same as just checking. All these implementations are however in some sense "unintelligent". First of all simply generating *a* solution can be done in poly time, and a more intelligent enumeration algorithm would require some sort of "no-good" learning (like clause learning is also capable to boost SAT effectively).

Comment: he didn't use lists, but simulated arrays IIRC (two compound terms with 2N-1 initially uninstantiated arguments; and arg/3 for the *immediate* store/check). classic  space for time trade-off. btw your pick_rem/3 is ~= select/3, and range = findall ... between; I take it you did it for didactic purposes... :)

Comment: @WillNess: yes, one could also use `between/3`, etc. As for Bratko's book, I think you reference to this? Looks to lists to me https://books.google.be/books?id=-15su78YRj8C&pg=PA109#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @WillNess: If I follow the link, I get page 109 (well it continues to page 111).

Comment: ah, yes: 3rd ed, p 190 - "simulating arrays with *arg*". discusses this optimization for the queens problem.

Comment: @WillNess: but that works only for the 8-queens problem (or well a fixed number-queens), since it works with *fixed* arity functor. Furthermore it also makes assumptions on how the interpreter will store the functor, since for example tuples are stored like `(1,4,2,5) == (1, (4, (2, 5)))` which looses the performance increase (more or less, yes it will probably be a bit more efficient, since the matching is done in "bulk").

Comment: we'd create them with `functor(X,f,15)` or 19, or whatever; etc. (two sets of 2N-1 diagonals)

Comment: @WillNess: yes, but (a) the question is how it is implemented under the hood. Since Prolog does not specify how it is implemented, (b) in many cases the arity of such functor is limited to ~1000, which means that it can only work up to *n=500*.

Comment: even Integers are limited, if not by CPU design then by the memory limitations. :)

Comment: @WillNess: yes, but typically by the size of the memory (like you said), and with reasonable bounds (not ~500 :)). Furthermore one could attach virtual memory, or use a network, which can make the memory ~1'200 petabytes (given the world would get interested in calculating an N-quens). But reglardless the problem can be solved in *O(n^3)* with gradient descent for *a* solution, so why bother performing enumeration?

Comment: do you have any links for that n^3 thing? .... google gives this: http://algolist.manual.ru/maths/combinat/nqueens.php ...

Comment: @WillNess: yes https://fizyka.umk.pl/~milosz/AlgIILab/10.1.1.57.4685.pdf the upperbound is n^3, but in reality it is typically even O(n log n). They solve 500k-queens problems with a 25 MHz motorola :)